# Is there a way in Chrome to use SSL by default?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

What I would like to do is have Chrome automatically switch me to SSL connections if a site supports it.

So if I type for example: `www.somesite.com` in the browser I want Chrome to try to connect me straight to `https://www.somesite.com` if it doesn't exist, then redirect me to plain text **http**.

Is there a setting, plugin or some way to do this?

**Update:** The **Electronic Frontier Foundation** have a tool called [HTTPS Everywhere](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) for Firefox which does this but it's Firefox only.

Comment: This question seems a little too old to answer, but [HTTPS Everywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp?hl=en) is now available for Chrome too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Secure Sites](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hllceldkphjbfpchpfmcgaeafheplfog) extension for Chrome.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge there isn't a plugin that does this. Without actually trying to go to the site as https there is no information on a page to tell you if it is even listening for secure requests.

Currently your best bet is to bookmark the sites that you use frequently as https and visit them through those links.

Comment: What if I click on a link to a site I haven't visited before. I want an SSL connection without using bookmarks or typing HTTPS manually as I do now.